# Adding thousands separator for custom formatted highcharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to in my app and want to add tooltip with thousand separator like I did it in data labels. I used custom formatting for tooltip, so what should I change to achieve this

tooltip options in highcharts

```
tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.x + ':' + this.y);
                },
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shahinul87/s81cnw79/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use thousand separator in lang

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({

    lang: {
      decimalPoint: '.',
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

and in tooltip- formatter use like

```
   tooltip: {
             pointFormat: '<b>{point.x} :</b>' + 'Count: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>',

            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        }
```

[Updated fiddle with separator without decimal point](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/s81cnw79/4/)

Comment: please take a look in the fiddle

Comment: if don't want decimal part replace .1f with .0f  pointFormat: '  <b>{point.x} :</b>' + 'Count: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'

Comment: :) I was making your desired format ,Initially I made it with 1 decimal point .Check the fiddle now

Comment: The fiddle(s) is/are gone now. Is it possible to re-upload it?

Comment: jsfiddle page does not exists

Comment: @Irrfan23, please refer another answer given by  that fiddle is still available

Answer (score 6):

Just following Nishith Kant Chaturvedi's answer, and since there is no jsfiddle example available, here you can see how to implement that answer.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      decimalPoint: '.',
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Salary']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{total:,.2f} $us'
        },
        labels: {
            format: "{value:,.2f} $us",
        }
    },
    legend: {
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                    format: '{point.y:,.2f} $us',
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
            type: 'column',
        name: 'Tomas',
        data: [60000]
    }, {
            type: 'column',
        name: 'Amy',
        data: [18000]
    }, {
            type: 'column',
        name: 'Jenny',
        data: [85000]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zrc5skLy/

Comment: Great answer! Helped me finally get the $1,000,000 formatting correct.  You can modify the formatting of the highlighted values by using '{series.name}:  {point.y:,.2f}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal:,.2f}'.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Highcharts.numberFormat()` in point.x or point.y

example:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: true,
  split: true,
  shared: true,
  formatter: function () {
    // The first returned item is the header, subsequent items are the points
    return [Highcharts.dateFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", this.x)].concat(
      this.points
        ? this.points.map(function (point) {
            return (
              point.series.name +
              ": " +
              // numberFormat(data, decimal)
              Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2)
            );
          })
        : []
    );
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this option is not available in our framework,

```
lang: {
      decimalPoint: '.',
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
```

I came up with a trick using point formatter

```
"pointFormatter": "function (){ return (this.base/1000).toString().replace('.', ',')}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).